# transform.Translate isn't cutting it and rigidbody.AddRelativeForce doesn't move my character (Unity and c#)

Tags: c#, game-engine, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 5 (3D) and am using c# for scripting. So I basically have a third person dude running around with 8 direction controls (WASD) and the way I have set it up now is like this (ignore all the public variables for testing):

```
public class Player8D : MonoBehaviour
{
public float moveSpeed;
public float moveSpeedMax = 13.5F;
public float turnSpeed = 4F;
public float transitionSpeed = 10F;
private float moveSmooth = 0.0F;
public float moveSmoothTime = 10F;
private Animator anim;
private Rigidbody rb;
private CharacterController cc;

void Start()
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    rb = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>();
    cc = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 NextDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    if (NextDir != Vector3.zero) //When movement input is happening

    {
        anim.SetInteger("Run", 1); //Animation stuff
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(NextDir), Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
        moveSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(moveSpeed, moveSpeedMax, ref moveSmooth, moveSmoothTime / 100);
    } else
    {
        moveSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(moveSpeed, 0.00F, ref moveSmooth, transitionSpeed / 100);
        anim.SetInteger("Run", 0);   //Animation stuff
        anim.CrossFade("Idle", transitionSpeed / 100);
    }
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed); //Movement code
 }
}
```

This gave me the best feeling due to how it moves in the direction it's facing, rather than in 8 distinct world directions like with cc.Move. That being said it has the caveat of not being in physics, which I kinda need for OnTriggerEnter and falling realistically and it makes going uphill strange. I have no idea how to manage the rb.AddForce or AddRelativeForce functions, as they don't move my character when I replace transform.Translate with them, no matter how great the force is.
How do I change the code and components to get my character moving through physics?

Here is a screenshot of my scene hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: Where on your character's hierarchy is your Rigidbody located? Can you include a screenshot of its location/properties?

Comment: @Serlite Here you go [Editor screenshot](https://postimg.org/image/dadxfhnnj/)